# json structure for selecting 'some' or 'all' elements of array

Tags: json

In below json structure, I am trying to specify either 'some' or 'all' elements of an array? Is this correct?

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "colours": ["green", "red"]
    },
    {
      "colours": [ "*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: JSON is just a data format, it bears only the meaning you give to it. So if you feel `*` conveys the message of "all", then that's fine. BTW: your JSON is incomplete -- it cannot start like that.

Comment: @trincot thanks. However, server needs a implementation to check type of array element i.e., either a wildcard pattern or some value. btw, I corrected the json

Comment: @trincot ..this is another way but bit lengthy. not sure which is the good-   {
  "input": [
    {
      "name": "colours",
      "valueType": "array",
      "value": ["green", "red"]
    },
        {
      "name": "colours",
      "valueType": "string",
      "value": "*"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Without information on what the server expects, how can we possibly answer this question?

Comment: server implementation yet to be done :)